# Chat oneboxes Github gists too big

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Case in point: [gist in C++ chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3144227#3144227). It fills the whole screen. Or, [as DeadMG puts it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3144233#3144233):

> whoah, giant wall'o'text

I suggest reducing the `max-height` by half, i.e. 300px. That should be enough.

Comment: +1 People should understand their code and only include the relevant parts, otherwise explain what their code does (which is usually just copying the comments if you're clean coding). I think this is by-design though, so you might want to turn it into a feature request instead where it is `300px` by default and an `expand link` is available just like how the normal fixed font chat messages function...

Comment: @Tom Bugs can be by design. As far as I’m concerned this is a UI bug.

Comment: I was referring more to [status-bydesign], perhaps it has been done with a reason...

Comment: @TomWijsman this is the only type of onebox that takes up so much screen estate. Wikipedia, Twitter messages/profiles, SO questions, etc. all seem more reasonable, and the exception for the github onebox violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: the Amazon box is also pretty huge, but not quite as big as the gists

Comment: Code you enter directly into the textbox is more limited than oneboxed gists. If anything, it should be the other way around. This is silly.

Comment: @sehe: Actually [there are other onebox types that can take up more space](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8046867#8046867).